# PHP Showing push notifications to client

Tags: php, push-notification

I am getting a real time server side notifications from instagram when a photo is tagged with a certain name.

I now need to push them to client.Is there any php classes that I can use to push notifications to client?

Can I implement the comet model for this? If so, How do I implement it?

Shed some light on this.It would be great,if you suggest better way of doing this.I've not done push notifications.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm concerned this cannot be done with php alone, unless the html page was automatically submitted back to the server... You want to use ajax. I've found that using jQuery is the simplest way.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

you use it like:

```
$.get('ajax/new_notifications.php', function(data) {
    $('.notification-area').html(data);
});
```

This will process the new_notification.php file, and return the echo'ed results into the `.notification-area`

Comment: :The above solution cannot be used in this scenario because we are only receiving a POST request to the new_notification.php file. When that request happens, we have to send a notification to all connected users (clients).